# How to route to Virtual IP as gateway

Tags: centos, load-balancing, haproxy, failover

I have environment on Centos 6.7 Final,
2 Loadbalancer failover (Haproxy, keepalived),
3 Web Server (nginx - PHP-Fpm).

LB1 (Public x.x.x.233, Private 10.110.120.21),
LB2 (Public x.x.x.235, Private 10.110.120.23),
Virtual (Public x.x.x.234, Private 10.110.120.22)

Web server 1,2,3 (Private 10.110.120.31,32,33),
Gateway 10.110.120.22 (Virtual IP)

Currently target accepted 233,234,235.

Question is how to route permanent which target accept Public IP x.x.x.234 only (Virtual Public IP) ?

Regards,

Pathic